# Give the usual estimator of \theta?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference

I am given a random sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ (of size n) from the exponential distribution whose pdf is $f_\theta(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ for $0 < x < \infty.$

I am asked to give the "usual estimator of $\theta.$"

The answer is: "Since $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\frac{1}{\theta})$, we know that $E(X) = \theta$ and we can estimate $\theta$ with the empirical sample mean."

Why isn't the answer to this question $\frac{1}{\theta}$ since the exponential distribution has an expectation of $\frac{1}{\theta}$?

Comment: Because the parameter is $\theta$. Nevertheless by taking the reciprocal you can write the estimator for  $\frac1{\theta}$.

Comment: I have no idea what is "the usual estimator" of a parameter. The most common (by far) estimates are the $\mathsf{ML}$ estaimes (for "maximum likelihood"). Note that the exponential distribution can be parametrised as $\theta e^{-\theta x}$ and as $\frac{1}{\theta} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}},$ in the first case the mean is $\frac{1}{\theta}$ and in the second case it is $\theta,$ is it is always better to specify something like "Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with mean $\theta.$" In this way, confusion shall never arrive...

Comment: At any rate, in your problem $E(X) = \theta$ and the sample mean is _an_ estimator. The sample mean will also be the $\mathsf{ML}$ estimator of the population mean. A very important property of $\mathsf{ML}$ estimators is that they are invariant under bijective transformations of parameters, so if $\hat \theta$ is the $\mathsf{ML}$ estimate of one parametrisation, then $\frac{1}{\hat \theta}$ is the $\mathsf{ML}$ estimate of the other.

Comment: $f_\theta(x) = \frac{1}{\theta} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ leads to an expectation of the scale parameter $\theta$ while $f_\lambda(x) = \theta e^{-\lambda x}$ leads to an expectation of the reciprocal of the rate parameter i.e. $\frac1\lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Other comments or observations.**

Assume the following. You have a independent and identically distributed random variables, say $X_1, \ldots, X_n.$ Suppose that these random variables follow some distribution $F$ on $\mathbf{R},$ so that $\mathbf{P}(X_1 \in \mathrm{A}) = \int\limits_\mathrm{A} F(dx).$ Suppose $F$ has a finite first moment, that is $\int\limits_{\mathbf{R}} |x| F(dx) < \infty$ and call $\mu = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} x F(dx)$ the first moment of $F.$ The "method of moments" estimator of $\mu$ is, by definition, $\bar X = \bar X(n):= \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n X_i.$ Simple linearity of the expectation shows at once that $\mathbf{E}(\bar X) = \mu$ and the law of large numbers show that $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \bar X = \mu.$ These two properties are deisrable, the first one is called "unbiasdness" and the second one is called "consistency." Therefore, for *any distribution whatsoever*, the sample mean define a sequence of estimators that are unbiased and the sequence is consistent.

Now, if is often the case that statisticians assume much more than the previous paragraph, explicitly, they assume that $F(dx) = f_\theta(x) dx,$ where $\theta \in \Theta \subset \mathbf{R}^q,$ and $(x, \theta) \to f_\theta(x)$ is smooth in some sense. Under these circumstances, they construct the "likelihood function" which is $L(X_1, \ldots, X_n; \theta) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^n f_\theta(X_i)$ and maximise this function in $\theta$ for observed $X_1, \ldots, X_n.$ This procedure constructs $\hat \theta = \hat \theta(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in \Theta$ which is known as the "maximum likelihood estimate" of the parameter $\theta.$ Under general conditions on $(x, \theta) \mapsto f_\theta(x),$ the maximum likelihood estimate is the best estimator, and it is often the case (but not always!) that when $\theta = \int\limits_\mathbf{R} x f_\theta(x) dx$ ($\theta$ is the population mean when the "true model" is $f_\theta$) then $\hat \theta = \bar X.$ An important result regarding estimators of a "parameter" is that estimators should not depend on the parameter, but solely on the sample (they are functions of $(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ but not of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n, \theta)$).